# Using GeoLocation Maps defaultly How to show the currentLocation in Us in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios4, google-maps, dictionary

Hi friends i am new iphone developer i am using the below code in currentlocaiton. But my superior asking he want defaultly showing us(united states) location but my code showing currentlocaiton in india. please tell me how to locate the default location in US.

```
IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView; 

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    //mapView.delegate=self;
    mapView.mapType=MKMapTypeStandard;
    mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    //mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

My code is defaultly showing Europe location but i want Us location what we do please tell me i am straggle for this concept.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the latitude and longitude for US. Example:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
location.latitude = XX.XXXXX;
location.longitude = XXX.XXXXX;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Prasad: Glad it helps. If it works, maybe you could vote the answer, so others will know this solution works.